# What is the colContainer property and where i can find its documentation

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have just started to discover the [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) last couple of days.
The documentation of the [ui.grid.class:GridOptions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions) shows an example on how to use the `rowTemplate` property :

**rowTemplate**

'ui-grid/ui-grid-row' by default. When provided, this setting uses a custom row template. Can be set to either the name of a template file:

```
$scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = 'row_template.html';
```

inline html

```
$scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = '<div style="background-color: aquamarine" ng-click="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell></div>';
```

As you can see in the `rowTemplate` html code there is an `ng-repeat` which iterates over `colContainer.renderedColumns`'s `col` items and there is the `track by` option which uses `col.colDef.name`.

the same template was also used in the [317_custom_templates tutorial example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates).

I was looking in the documentation for the origin of the `colContainer` property and i only could found a property having the same name under [ui.grid.cellNav.object:CellNav](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.cellNav.object:CellNav) without any details for it (i already don't know if it's exactly the same `colContainer` property used in the `rowTemplate` example above and in the [317_custom_templates tutorial example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates) because in the [202 Cell Navigation tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav) it's said :
`> To enable, you must include the 'ui.grid.cellNav' module` and in the [317_custom_templates tutorial example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates) there is no such as injection for this module)
there is also a property `sourceColContainer` under the [ui.grid.class:ScrollEvent](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav) but it's not the same poperty name but maybe it can be its origin.

I would like to find the `colContainer` property's documentation and understand it better and know what are its own sub-properties if any exists (other than the `colDef.name`) or at least i would know its origin and look into its code source if there is no documentation for it maybe that would be useful too.

Best regards.

Comment: i found that col is from the class http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridColumn

Answer (score 1):

I found this */src/js/core/directives/ui-grid-render-container.js:47* :

```
 var colContainer = $scope.colContainer = grid.renderContainers[$scope.colContainerName];
```

So colContainer is in fact a render Container that you can access outside directives and templates by doing `$scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers["nameOfColContainer"]`

to know the `nameOfColContainer` you will have to check your template here

---

(*/src/templates/ui-grid/ui-grid.html:33*) :

```
 <div ui-grid-render-container
      container-id="'body'"
      col-container-name="'body'"
      row-container-name="'body'"
      bind-scroll-horizontal="true"
      bind-scroll-vertical="true"
      enable-horizontal-scrollbar="grid.options.enableHorizontalScrollbar"
      enable-vertical-scrollbar="grid.options.enableVerticalScrollbar">
    </div>
```

So it is most certainly body. Within a renderContainer you will have an object called renderedColumns which contains the columns to be rendered.
**You can also access other containers other than 'body' : left and right**.
This is if you use pinned left and/or right, body being the center container.